# How can I track down why starting a Windows service fails immediately with error 1053?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service

I'm trying to start a Windows service by right-clicking on it in Services and choosing Start.

Immediately (less than a second) a dialog comes up with error 1053. Odd because I thought services were given 30 seconds to start.

In the event log, I get two entries, first saying the 30,000 ms timeout was reached, and the second about the service no responding in a timely fashion.

I don't find any other relevant event log entries. Are there any ways to track down why the service doesn't start?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Is it the same service each time? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, it's the same service each time. The service was purchased from a third party, it's not a normal Windows one.

Comment: FWIW, uninstalling .NET 4.0 fixed this issue, the service does use CLR 2. Still wondering if there's any tools/logs to track down the root cause.

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed. You could investigate the logs for .NET (I'm not at a Windows machine right now to tell you exactly where to look).